# How to unpack an expression tree and check for null values

Tags: c#, linq, expression, lambda

With reference to the 2 classes below, I am regularly writing LINQ statements like this..

```
using (var db = new DBContext())
{
    var result = db.Countries
        .Select(c => new
        {
            c.Name,
            c.Leader != null ? c.Leader.Title : String.Empty,
            c.Leader != null ? c.Leader.Firstname : String.Empty,
            c.Leader != null ? c.Leader.Lastname : String.Empty
        });
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Leader Leader { get; set; }
}

public class Leader
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

My issues that I am having to constantly repeat my null checks on children navigation properties and I was wondering if there is a way I can use some kind of expression tree to extract the property values dynamically whilst checking for null values and if they didn't exist send back an empty string, something like the method below..

```
public class Country
{
    // Properties //

    public string SafeGet(Expression<Func<Country, string>> fnc)
    {
        // Unpack fnc and check for null on each property?????
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
using (var db = new DBContext())
{
    var result = db.Countries
        .Select(c => new
        {
            c.Name,
            c.SafeGet(l => l.Leader.Title),
            c.SafeGet(l => l.Leader.Firstname),
            c.SafeGet(l => l.Leader.Lastname)
        });
}
```

If someone could provide a basic example that would be great as I don't have a whole lot of experience with expression tree's other than creating them.

Thanks.

**Update** -> would something like the following work?

```
public string GetSafe(Expression<Func<Country, string>> fnc)
{
    var result = fnc.Compile().Invoke(this);
    return result ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Frankly, this is doable but will be too much trouble for little gain (and almost certainly you would need to only support specific constructs otherwise you 're doing even more work for no practical benefit). Your suggested solution won't work.

Comment: It seems you could achieve something more concise by first creating a leader with empty properties with `var defaultLeader = new Leader { Title = "", Firstname = "" }` and then use the null-coalescing `(c.Leader ?? defaultLeader).Title`. Extra bonus: works for all other property types too.

Comment: @Jon - I was thinking I could put the GetSafe method in a base generic class to be used by a number of other classes.. Also, in my example I am just using the Leader property however in practise there could be up to 5 or 6 different properties. I guess that would mean I would have to create that many defaultProperties for your proposed solution?

Comment: Yes, you 'd need many.

Comment: Have a look at NullSafe [here](http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-one/). But it really gets helpful when you're descending deeper, here it actually won't save you much typing.

Comment: @Jon (and OP): If all those properties' values are default, shouln't a simple `c.Leader ?? new Leader()` suffice? You'd only have to specify any custom values you want; it will use the default property values otherwise.

Comment: @Flater: Isn't that exactly what `defaultLeader` does, with the additional tweak that there's a single "default" instance instead of one being created per access expression?

Comment: Yes, my point was more about the fact that if in the old code, default values are used in case of null (`c.Leader != null ? c.Leader.Title : String.Empty`), there's no need to actually *set specific default values* in your defaultLeader, as those (value) properties already have the 'correct' value. So you'd only have to metion any property if you wanted its value to be anything other than default. Of reference properties, if you don't want null to be used as default. Whether you put the defaultLeader in a variable or not was not my intended point :)

Comment: I tend to add a `public static Leader Default()` method (or property, either way) to my classes so that I can define its default inside of the class, rather than inside the business logic that works with the class. Seems more organized. But I accept that it's subjective.

Answer (score 1):

I see no need for an expression. I would simply go for an extension-method like

```
    public static class ModelExtensions
    {
         // special case for string, because default(string) != string.empty 
         public static string SafeGet<T>(this T obj, Func<T, string> selector)
         {
              try {
                  return selector(obj) ?? string.Empty;
              }
              catch(Exception){
                  return string.Empty;
              }
         }
   }
```

It works for all classes and you could implement further for other datatypes. The usage is the same as yours.

Comment: Shouldn't it include catching of NullReferenceExceptions too?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something like this:

```
public static class ModelExtensions
{
    public static TResult SafeGet<TSource, TResult>(this TSource obj, System.Func<TSource, TResult> selector) where TResult : class
    {
        try
        {
            return selector(obj) ?? default(TResult);
        }
        catch(System.NullReferenceException e)
        {
            return default(TResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @golergka, your code does not compile, i get the following error "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TResult' and 'TResult'"

Comment: Hi @gorlenka, `default(string)` is not `string.Empty` like @Grant is expecting.